# Google Cloud OAuth verification

Tags: oauth, google-cloud-platform, google-oauth

I recently received an email from the Google Cloud Platform Team notifying me of a policy violation stating that we had not completed the OAuth developer verification process and we're limited to 100 new user grants of which we're already at 60% towards.

The thing is, if I view this Oauth consent screen in the Google Cloud Platform, at the top of the page, it states:

```
Your consent screen is being verified. This may take up to several days. Your last approved consent screen is still in use.
```

This page was last saved and 'submitted for verification' some months ago now.

The page itself is constantly glitchy and poor anyway I've noticed at various points in the past.

The information this page contains is correct and I am unable to re-submit for verification unless I make changes.

Nonetheless, I'll make a change, resubmit, then edit removing that change and resubmit again but it's proving to be a bit of a hassle when either their system doesn't work or we're waiting on them to approve/reject the Oauth verification.

Am I supposed to be doing something else or is there a workaround at all?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70528223/14206384

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you've taken a look at the App Verification help page:
https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/7454865?hl=en

and the much more detailed verification FAQ:
https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/9110914

From the sounds of your post, it seems like you probably just need to get your app's branding verified because you are accessing sensitive scopes. That should be a pretty straightforward process if you have everything ready for review. Make sure you haven't gotten any messages from the review team with open items you need to accomplish. If not, you can make a trivial change and resubmit.

If you are trying to access a restricted scope like Gmail APIs, the process will be much more involved. Make sure you have all your requirements taken care of as outlined in the FAQ. And be sure you look closely at what scopes your code is actually requesting. If you are asking for sensitive or restricted scopes in your app but don't have those fully registered and approved in the developer console, your users will get warnings and you'll have restricted tokens revoked.

Comment: Why would something like this take "several weeks" which is what Google is noting in the UI when you submit for verification.  How can we expedite the process?