# Example of an OAuth Homepage for Google

Tags: flutter, google-oauth

I have created a flutter application in both iOS and Android that uses OAuth2. In order to authenticate the the app. While I can sign in successfully on iOS, Android provides error the following error:

```
E/flutter ( 6309): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(sign_in_failed, com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10: , null)
```

This is almost certainly because of a configuration issue in my OAuth verification request. Their rejection (see below) describes a homepage they require:

> Dear Developer,
>
> Thank you for submitting an OAuth App Verification request.
>
> Unfortunately, we cannot proceed further with the verification process
>   until the requested things are provided.
>
> As we discussed in our previous communication, to proceed with the
>   verification process for your project what-happend-here  you will need
>   to provide a homepage that accurately represents your app’s identity
>   to Google users.
>
> Every OAuth2 project requires a homepage. To ensure users’
>   understanding of your app’s purpose, your homepage should:
>
> - Be a verified domain under your ownership
> - Be accurate, inclusive, and easily accessible to all users
> - Link to an externally accessible domain that describes the necessary content, context, or connection to the app you are submitting
> - Explain with transparency the purpose for which your application requests user data
> - etc.

However, despite the description, I've no feel of what it should be like. Is there an example of such a page that I can use as a model?
Thanks for any help.

Comment: I am actually looking to get the same homepage example for google oauth approval. have you found the solution to this? any homepage examples we can check out?

Answer (score 22):

I've been back and forth with google over this issue. I can't give a simple answer, but I can summarize the items I've changed in order to meet compliance.

For context, I'm just using oauth on my personal webpage to identify users. I'm not selling an app. I'm not using restricted scopes. I'm not touching any user data.

This should be the simplest case, yet it was difficult to get approval. Each rejection reply is in the style of a form letter. I conclude that an AI has be trained against a set of compliant pages, and it "feels" mine isn't compliant, i.e. it's not able to point to a specific violation like a human or a rule's based system would. For this reason, I advise against spending time in your email replies. It doesn't seem that anyone reads them, just change your content and reply to get the AI to look again.

In the google console you must provide:

- a homepage url
- a privacy policy url
- an uploaded icon image file

If you're using oauth for a website, don't confuse the oauth console "homepage url" with the base url of your website. Google wants a "homepage" that says "what your app is".

The content served at the homepage must have a [link rel="shortcut icon"] whose href points to the identical bytes of the icon you uploaded in the oauth console. If the bytes differ because you're using a scaled or differently styled image, you'll be rejected.

The content served at the homepage must have a privacy policy link where the href is identical to the characters entered at the console. If they're the same page, but differ by an anchor for example, you'll be rejected.

Also watch for caching. I changed the contents of my [link rel="shortcut icon"/] and got a reply that seemed to accept the icon but complain about another issue. Then when I fixed the other issue they rejected me for the icon again. I think since I changed the uploaded icon but didn't change it's name that they later saw a cached icon. I changed just the url (thus invalidating their cache) and the next reply didn't complain about the icon.

If you're not using restricted scopes you shouldn't need the limited use disclosure, but I got a complaint about that so I added it.

Here's what I'm using for both the homepage and the privacy policy:
https://holtstrom.com/michael/about/

Here's how that looked at the time of this posting when it was finally approved.

[image]

You'll see that I have all of the google requirements rendered in underline followed by the text that satisfies the requirement.

In case it helps, here's the replies I received from Google:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: The only actually helpful info I can find on this on the internet.  Going to try to spin up a "home" page that has the described info in place of the landing page URL I've currently provided (and been rejected on).  I don't understand why this is such a pain, but thank you for taking the time to detail your response!

Comment: I can't find the menu where you are supposed to fill in the "homepage". could you point me to the right direction ?

Comment: @julianalimin re. "fill in the homepage": console.cloud.google.com > OAuth consent screen > Edit app > Application home page

Comment: First of all this is bizarre policy. I am not understanding why they need a homepage for an app only function. If they wanted the usage/policy to be displayed in the app, that would have made more sense.

Comment: man, that is so annoying, we used to verify bunch of apps and getting feedback from their team of what has to be fixed. Now they are keep rejecting new apps just saying "u violate our policy, bye". What policy? Whats wrong? I don't know who they hired for those checks, but its almost impossible to verify anything. sigh

Comment: This helped me a lot also. The information, together with the information you get from Google, is very helpful. I got an approval the third time through. I didn't have to send in a video, but I'm not using restricted APIs. I'm only using the application backup service. Concerning `[link rel="shortcut icon"]`, I got this to work with just `[link rel="icon"]`.

Comment: Thanks for such detailed explanation Michael. It worked like a charm. The  "homepage"  word used by Google confused me until I read your solution

Answer (score 7):

### Google OAuth Consent Screen Verification:

@Michael Holtstrom's answer works perfectly, And I got my app approved in just the 2nd attempt.

But, since there is no information available anywhere on internet regarding this, that's why

I am posting my answer with all the screenshots, only to support @Michael Holtstrom's answer, so that you can move ahead with more confidence.

Because, I was really worried for 3-4 days whether my app will get approved or not. Because this was the last part left in my project.

### I was also using Google OAuth only to get email, name and profile picture.

My app could have got approved in the first attempt only, but the first time I submited homepage had text selection disabled(Because I built it using Flutter Web, on which text selection is disbaled by default).

So, I think the Google's AI was unable to read the text on homepage, and thus asked me to update the homepage.

Next time, I built using wordpress, and then my app got approved.

(And by the way, I'm using chrome extension `dark reader`, that's why all the screenshot has dark mode enabled.)

### Youtube Video Url:

https://youtu.be/lzq9WjCXT6c

### Consent screen form on GCP Console

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

### Google OAuth Homepage

https://www.madhavkumar.in/about/
[image]

### Privacy Policy

https://www.madhavkumar.in/privacy-policy/
[image]

### Email thread with Google Trust Team

[image]
[image]