# Google OAuth Consent Screen Mobile App Verification

Tags: google-api, youtube-data-api, google-oauth, google-console-developer

Trying to get my consent screen verified, as my iOS mobile app uses YouTube's API to get their YouTube subscriptions (this falls under the 'sensitive' scope, not 'restricted'). Info on it can be found here -> https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/9110914?hl=en

The consent verification form requires an "Authorized Domain" and also a "Homepage" for the app. The problem is that this is a iOS app and I don't have a website or a URL to give this form.

The consent form:

[image]

**What do I put in the place of the Authorized Domain and Homepage links?**

or

**Am I going about the verification process all wrong? Is there another way for mobile apps?**

Comment: Hi, 

I've got the same problem. Did you find solution for this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70528223/14206384 I hope ot helps.

Answer (score 0):

First, if you don't have a domain for it then it is impossible to remove the unverified stuff on your screen.

Second, the domain field is something like google.com, youtube.com where you going to attach the tag for verification. Which, this domain currently you don't have.

Third, the application homepage link is your website.

Lastly, from my experience no special cases for mobile and web process when it comes to that stuff showing on the screen.

The app will show that unverified screen once you are using a sensitive scope that requires app verification regardless if it's a mobile app or web app.