# Google OAuth verification is torcher

Tags: google-oauth

I am not sure this is the place to post it but as it costumes us Developers we go and complain to other Developers. So my problem is as follows I am verifying my consent screen for Google OAuth I did this process for at least 7 apps by now and it was always fine. But currently the tester I got just keeps failing not only does he refuse to answer with normal text but instead realize only on email templates every time I fix one thing he does not like he finds some other thing. Now I understand how it sounds but I am not just whining for example one of his requests was to change the home page to some different website that is not related to my app in any way. Or the latest thing was that he did not see a consent screen in the video while it is clear there I even pointed out to him the exact time. So now I am getting an email that changes need to be made I explain to him that everything is ok and 24 hours after I am getting a new request for changes. And there is absolutely no one to talk to no one to complain to. If someone knows what to do I would be really grateful.

Comment: This question can really benefit from a clear title, paragraphs and all emotions removed.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70528223/14206384 I hope it helps.